# Android - TextView in Material Design using Support Library

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

how can I make TextView in Material Design using Support Library by code (inside AlertDialog)?

My code (doesn't work):

```
   AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);

   final TextInputLayout input = new TextInputLayout(this);
   input.addView(new EditText(this));
   input.getEditText().setHint(R.string.enter_pass);

   alert.setView(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.
It should be

```
input.setHint(getString(R.string.enter_pass));
```

not

```
input.getEditText().setHint(R.string.enter_pass);
```